# Difficulty in getting GitBook site to show up in GitHub page

Tags: git, command-line, github

I am trying to follow https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook but there is some assumed knowledge that clearly I don't have. I've used GitHub for some time but I've still got a lot to learn.

My goal is to have a [GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/) at http://martynchamberlin.github.io/GitBook/ that corresponds to this repository: https://github.com/martynchamberlin/GitBook.

So here's my question: *how exactly is GitBook themselves doing this?*

I assume (though it's not anywhere stated) that they are manually creating a gh-pages branch, because this magically turns a Github repo into a Github page.

To do this, I have followed the Github documentation at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually

But here's my problem: all of the HTML (index.html, etc) is located at /_book/ instead of in the parent directory of the gh-pages branch. Which means that when I load https://github.com/martynchamberlin/GitBook, I'm getting a 404.

Note that when I run `gitbook serve` locally, I see what I'm supposed to when I fire up my browser at localhost:4000.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Martyn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this book: https://github.com/GitbookIO/git.

It uses grunt to set up a few tasks: test, publish and build.

You should do the same by copying the package.json, Gruntfile.js and running:

```
$ npm install .
```

For testing:

```
$ grunt test
```

For publishing on the gh-pages branch:

```
$ grunt publish
```

Comment: WOW!!!! Voila. Boom. Magic. I guess you take it for granted that other people know about this. I certainly didn't... missed the memo somehow. But this did the trick. Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't see the package.json, Gruntfile.js files in that project, any more.

Comment: Same here . @samy-pessé can you confirm if the repository link you posted is still valid ?

Comment: I find the Gruntfile.js file in the tag _0.0.5_

Answer (score 0):

for people who still have issues using the command above, here is my scenario.

I used to use `tortoise-git` on my windows machine  to manage my github projects, and they are totally fine tool to use. But when it comes to `gitbook publish` command, it somehow stuck in the middle of switching between branches etc...

My solution is to download the **github windows client**, and it has this `git shell` come with it , if you run the `gitbook publish` command against the github suite git tooling, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `gh-pages` branch, you are correct, it can be found here:

https://github.com/GitbookIO/git/tree/gh-pages

It does indeed have an `index.html` file in the root directory:

https://github.com/GitbookIO/git/blob/gh-pages/index.html