# how to serve my own gitbook using github pages

Tags: github

I've created my own gitbook. looks good locally.

but how shall I integrate it into my github pages? Similar issues here [difficulty-in-getting-gitbook-site-to-show-up-in-github-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094647/difficulty-in-getting-gitbook-site-to-show-up-in-github-page)

I tried that approach as well, but I have problem setting the grunt up, and I also I would like to do that myself before using an integrated tool.

I tried to copy the generated _book folder to my github page folder, but that didn't workout as there are some encoding issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094647/difficulty-in-getting-gitbook-site-to-show-up-in-github-page)

I had this question because I don't understand github pages, the underlying steps involve

1. build the _book folder, this is the static content that will be served
2. create gh-pages branch copy the _book folder content into gh-pages
3. github will then serve the content

   the command `gitbook publish` will finish all 3 steps.  but I am not familiar with `grunt` as well , as `npm install .` is a pre-step.